# View only few non-continuous columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays

`=FILTER(Matrice_data;Matrice_nom=G2)`

Pretty straight forward. I type a name in G2 and I get all rows with this name. My problem is this one: the "matrice_data" contains many columns, like 30. I want to see only 5 or 6 of them in the filter (let say, A, C, F, DD, AL).

One important thing: I don't want to use `Query`. It works really well, but I have a hyperlink in some cells and `Query` doesn't see it, but `Filter` does.  I try filter of filter, but I guess I don't understand the logic, because I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use a filter function inside another filter function.

For example, if your data is in B2:E5, with headers in row B, you can use:

```
=filter(b2:e2 & filter(B2:E5,B2:B5 = "Martin"),(B7:E7 = "b") + (B7:E7="d"))
```

This will filter by name, and then by your column headers "b" and "d".

Answer (score 0):

One way is to hide the columns that you don't want to view, just right-clic on the column(s) to hide, and select hide column.

Another way is to create an auxiliary range that includes only the columns that you want to see, then use that range as FILTER parameter.

`={A:A, C:C, F:F, D:D, AL:AL}`

For further details see [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)